# When to use prototypical programming in JavaScript

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, prototyping

I've spent a good bit of time developing simple widgets for projects in the following way:

```
var project = project || {};

(function() {

  project.elements = {
    prop1: val1,
    prop2: val2
  }

  project.method1 = function(val) {
    // Do this
  }

  project.method2 = function(val) {
    // Do that
  }

  project.init = function() {
    project.method1(project.elements.prop1)
    project.method2(project.elements.prop2)
  }
})()

project.init();
```

But I've started to change my format to the following:

```
function Project() {
  this.elements = {
    prop1: val1,
    prop2: val2
  }

  this.method_one(this.elements.prop1);
  this.method_two(this.elements.prop2);
}

Project.prototype.method_one = function (val) {
  // 
};

Project.prototype.method_two = function (val) {
  //
};

new Project();
```

Granted, these are silly examples so dont get wrapped around the axel. But what is the functional difference and when should I pick one or the other?

Comment: I think your first code example will not work since project does not leave the scope. To use inheritance in JS you use prototyping. The first example is not meant to extend project, so reusability might be limited.

Comment: Yeah I accidentally put the `project` declaration inside the function. Updated.

Comment: same here. first example is static, second is object oriented.

Comment: I can't think of a single case where one option would be "better" than the other, other than keeping consistent with what is already in the codebase. I prefer using the prototype method, but that's just because I find it easier to use, not because of some generally accepted fact or idea.

Comment: If you are using only ONE instance of object, then there is no reason whatsoever to use prototypal definition. And what you seem to need - is a module format - there is lot of options for that, see: http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/

Comment: First one for [singleton pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern) The second one for non-singleton (when 1 class can have many objects)

Comment: +1 first line I understood the magic behind the first part of the question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first difference can be summarized as: `this` refers to the *Instance* of the class. `prototype` refers to *Definition*.

Let's say we have the following class:

```
var Flight = function ( number ) { this.number = number; };
```

So here we are attaching `this.number` to every instance of the class, and it makes sense because every `Flight` should have their own flight number.

```
var flightOne = new Flight( "ABC" );
var flightTwo = new Flight( "XYZ" );
```

In contrast, `prototype` defines a single property that can be accessed by all of the instances.

Now if we want to get the flight number, we can simply write the following snippet and all of our instances will get a *Reference* to this newly prototyped object.

```
Flight.prototype.getNumber = function () { return this.number; };
```

The second difference is about the way that JavaScript searches for a property of an object. When you are looking for `Object.whatever`, JavaScript goes all the way up to the main *Object* object (the object that everything else has inherited from), and as soon as it finds a match it will return or call it.

But that only happens for the prototyped properties. So if you have somewhere in the higher tiers `this.whatever`, JavaScript won't consider it as a match and will continue the search.

Let's see how it happens in reality.

First note that [almost] everything are *Objects* in JavaScript. Try this:

```
typeof null
```

Now let's see what is inside an `Object` (note the Uppercase `O` and `.` in the end). In Google Chrome's Developer Tools when you enter the `.` you will get a list of available properties inside that specific object.

```
Object.
```

Now do the same thing for `Function`:

```
Function.
```

You may notice the `name` method. Just go and fire it up and let's see what happens:

```
Object.name
Function.name
```

Now let's create a function:

```
var myFunc = function () {};
```

And let's see if we got the `name` method here as well:

```
myFunc.name
```

You should get an empty string, but that's okay. You should not get an Error or Exception.

Now let's add something to that god-like `Object` and see if we get it in other places as well?

```
Object.prototype.test = "Okay!";
```

And there you go:

```
Object.prototype.test
Function.prototype.test
myFunc.prototype.test
```

In all cases you should see `"Okay!"`.

Regarding the pros and cons of each method you can consider prototyping as a "more-efficient" way of doing things, since it keeps a reference on every instance rather copying the whole property in each object. On the other hand it's an example of *Tightly Coupling* which is a big no-no until you can really justify the reason. `this` is quite more complicated since it's relevant to context. You can find a lot of good resources for free in the internet.

That all said, both ways are just language tools and it really depends to you and the problem you're trying to solve to pick what fits better.

If you need to have a property to be relevant to every instance of a class, then use `this`. If you need to have a property to function the same on every instance, then use `prototype`.

**Update**

Regarding your sample snippets, the first one is an example of *Singleton*, so it makes sense to use `this` within object body. You can also improve your example by making it modular like this (and you don't need to always use `this` as well).

```
/* Assuming it will run in a web browser */
(function (window) {
    window.myApp = {
        ...
    }
})( window );

/* And in other pages ... */
(function (myApp) {
    myApp.Module = {
        ...
    }
})( myApp );

/* And if you prefer Encapsulation */
(function (myApp) {
    myApp.Module = {
         "foo": "Foo",
         "bar": function ( string ) {
             return string;
         },
         return {
             "foor": foo,
             "bar": bar
         }
    }
})( myApp );
```

Your second snippet doesn't make that much sense because first you are using `this` and later you are trying to hack it with `prototype`, which doesn't work because `this` takes priority over `prototype`. I'm not sure what were your expectations from that piece of code and how it was working, but I highly recommend you to refactor it.

**Update**

To elaborate on `this` taking precedence on `prototype` I can show you an example and tell you how it can be explained, but I don't have any external resource to back it up.

The example is very simple:

```
var myClass = function () { this.foo = "Foo"; };
myClass.prototype.foo = "nice try!";
myClass.prototype.bar = "Bar";

var obj = new myClass;
obj.foo;     // Still contains "Foo" ...
obj.bar;     // Contains "Bar" as expected
```

The explanation is, as we know, `this` is relevant to the context. So it won't come to existence until the context is ready. When context is ready? When the new instance is being created! You should guess the rest now! It means that even though there is a `prototype` definition, but `this` makes more sense to take precedence because it's all about the new instance being created at that moment.

Comment: This is a partially epicly awesome answer! Can you edit it and go into further detail comparing and contrasting the two methods? Your first two paragraphs confuse me on which design method you're referring to. Your exercise is excellent! I never gave much thought to the power of prototyping like that. Can you also give a semi detailed case use example of when to use each method? Thanks again, this is great.

Comment: @JDillon522 Glad to hear that. I will try to update it in the next hours!

Comment: @JDillon522 Just did a quick update. Hope it will be more clear this time.

Comment: @JDillon522 A little bit more about your sample snippets ...

Comment: Nice singleton example. So I used `this` in the silly prototype example because `this` refers to its own properties, including its methods. I dont learn the best from reading about code, but more from looking at code. ([MDN's bit on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), [Object Playground (amazing)](http://www.objectplayground.com/), and a few others). Can you point to something that explains what you mean about "`this` takes priority over `prototype`"? I'd like to look into it more.

Comment: @JDillon522 updated!

Comment: @JDillon522 Welcome!